# using char for dynamic allocation

Tags: c++

I am trying to get my code to return, in this case, Monday or Tuesday, depending on the input.  On a telephone keypad, the digits for Monday are  666329, and the digits for Tuesday are 8837329.  So if the digits for Monday are read, then Monday should be output to the screen and vice versa. How can I get the code to return the day of the week using the digits provided in the if statements.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void setKey(char *keyPress);

int main()
{
    char *keyPress;

    keyPress = new char[10];

    setKey(keyPress);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void setKey(char *keyPress)
{
    cout << "Enter the day using the number keypad:   "<< endl << endl;
    cin >> keyPress;
    cout << endl << endl;

    if (keyPress == "666329")
        cout << "Monday" << endl << endl;
    else if (keyPress == "8837329")
        cout << "Tuesday" << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile, please show your actual code before asking. Note : you can't compare C strings that way.

Comment: What is your question? Also you should probably read a good C++ book first, this code has a lot of issues

Comment: You included `<string>`, so use `std::string`. There's also no need to `new` anything if you use it.

Comment: 1. `using namespace std;` is bad - search this site for the reason. 2. `setKey(char *keyPress);` - Where is the return type? 3. `k.setKey(keyPress);` Where is k declared? i.e. post code that compiles!

Comment: 1. This line `keyPress = new char;` is just allocating just one character!. 2. Why are you not using `std::string` and passing parameters as references?

Comment: 1. This does not work as expected `keyPress == "666329")` - look up `strcmp`. Also read `std::string` - would make your life a lot easier. Also read up about passing parameters by reference. Perhaps just read a book on C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason not use  `std::string` ?
A solution, using `std::string` would be:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void setKey(string& keyPress);

int main()
{
    string keyPress;
    setKey(keyPress);
    //rest here
}

void setKey(string& keyPress)
{
    cout << "Enter the day using the number keypad:   "<< endl << endl;
    cin >> keyPress;
    cout << endl << endl;

    if (keyPress == "666329")
        cout << "Monday" << endl << endl;
    else if (keyPress == "8837329")
        cout << "Tuesday" << endl << endl;
}
```

If you still want to use `c-style` strings, you need to compare them with the following function:
[strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Moreover, you have a memory leak in your code. You are using `new` without `delete`.